# A variation on the birthday paradox

Tags: probability, birthday-paradox

A question to the community:

Given N persons, and a period of M months, what is the probability at least one will have a birthday within the period?

P(bday in period) = N * (1/12) * (M/12)

This 'feels' too simple, can someone provide a correct approach?

Comment: This doesn't look like the Birthday Paradox at all.  It's a simple calculation once you realize the answer can be found from the chance that *nobody* will have a birthday during this period.  You are right to suspect your formula, because with large $N$ it can become greater than $1,$ making it obvious it can't always be a valid probability.

Comment: So the approach would be to explore 1-P(no birthday)?

Comment: So is it correct to think about: P(bday not in period) = ((12-M)/12)^N.   And therefore, P(bday in period) = 1-... ??

Comment: Yes, that's correct, as you suggest, you end up with $1-(1-\frac{M}{12})^N$. You might like to check it (by complete enumeration of cases) for simple examples like M=1, N=2 or M=6, N=3  (so it's a coin toss for each person of the three). Essentially the same question (about "at least one success in N trials", in different guises) has come up multiple times on site.

Comment: The same idea of using the complementary event can be found on Wikipedia; see the second calculation in this subsection: [**Complementary event**: Example of the utility of this concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event#Example_of_the_utility_of_this_concept)